# @Transient method call in Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have one Pojo class in which I create one field which is not mapped with DataBase Table.
So i have to declare the field Declaration and setter and getter method @Transient, otherwise it would have shown an error.

```
@Transient
private String docHistoryString="";

@Transient
public String getDocHistoryString() {
    return docHistoryString;
}

@Transient
public void setDocHistoryString(String docHistoryString) {
    this.docHistoryString = docHistoryString;
}
```

Now, my problem is in the controller. I have set some value in this transient field but when I try to access this variable using EL in view(JSP) it is not giving value. I think this is becouse I used the @transient annotation in get method.

Comment: Can you post the code that sets the docHistoryString and then returns it to the view?

Comment: @Transient is only used by Hibernate. It doesn't have any special meaning for Spring, Java in general, and the JSTL. The error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Hibernate annotations, including `@Transient` must be applied according to [access type](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e1955). By default it will be the same way as `@Id` applied. That is if you place `@Id` on a field you must apply `@Transient` to the field. And if you apply `@Id` to getter method, you must apply `@Transient` method. Setter methods are always ignored.

It can be customized, though (per documentation), so make sure that someone didn't do something strange with access types.

Answer (score 1):

According to this, it should be enough to declare the field/property

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Have you tried with just annotating the field/property? For further Help you have to post some more code snippets.