# How to Get @Transient Values in HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, annotations

I want to get @Transient values from HTML.I had tried @Basic,it creates entry in db. I need to get this value.

Pojo:

```
@Transient
private int  dueAmount;

public int getDueAmount() {
    return dueAmount =  this.getPaymentTotal() - this.getBillAmount() - this.getDiscountTotal();
}

public void setDueAmount(int dueAmount) {
    this.dueAmount = dueAmount;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/billByPatientId/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public List<Bill> getBillsByPatientId(@PathVariable("id") String patientId)throws Exception { 

    List<Bill> BillDetailsByPatientId  = billService.getBillsByPatientId(patientId);

    for(Bill b : BillDetailsByPatientId){
        System.out.println(b.getDueAmount());
    }
    return billService.getBillsByPatientId(patientId);
}
```

Js

```
$http.get('/bill/billByPatientId/'+patientData.id)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.bills = data;
});
```

HTML

```
 <table data-ng-show='bills.length > 0' class="table table-hover"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-1 text-center">Bill No</th>
                <th class="col-lg-3 text-center">Status</th>
            </tr>
</thead>
<tr data-ng-repeat="bill in bills">
    <td class="text-center">{{bill.billNo}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{bill.dueAmount}}</td>
</tr>
```

In my current code i get " dueAmount " value because of printing " dueAmount " in my Controller, otherwise values will be null.

How to do this ?

I Referrer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e1955) document

Comment: there are no values in HTML. Explain in more details what you are trying to achieve as it is not clear.

Comment: When u use `Transient` on property that property isn't stored in DB. Do u want this property's value from DB to HTML or something else ? U should elaborate more to get clear idea of what u want exactly. As u have specified in question **from HTML** it means u want that value from ur HTML form to ur controller or service class. M I right ?

Comment: Guys,I update my code,please make a view

Comment: I want to calculate dueAmount with my POJO calcultions(ie. without DB). how to do this

Comment: hi it looks good.. can you tell what your _console.log_ prints??

Comment: Also have a look at Have a look at Json objet andJson in java at http://json.org/java so that we JSONfy the response you return to JS get request

Comment: console prints data with dueAmount(because of sysout in my controller). My Problem in Java.

Comment: my question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012877/transient-method-call-in-spring-hibernate